# Can I obtain differents links for different installed theme?

Tags: themes, templates

I have to show 3 differents template to a person and then say to him: "Please, choose one of these templates and I will use it for your web site"

So the question is: **Have I to install 3 differents WP test websites (one for each templates) or can I install only one WP website and install on it 3 templates and give to him a differents links (one for a specific installed template)?**

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Do you mean *templates*, or *themes*? Is this like a demo site where you can 'test' against several different themes?

Comment: @Stephen Harris I mean themes, yes I need a demo site to show 3 different themes

Comment: Depends on how dramatic the template changes are. I've installed three themes on one install and then used a theme switcher plugin to switch between them until the client chooses one.

Answer (score 1):

I've done for this myself using the plug-in theme switcher: http://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-switcher/ (yes, it hasn't been edited in 2+ years).

These theme stores a cookie in the browser indicating which theme the user has selected (themes are displayed as a drop-down / link list widget - and selecting a theme changes the cookie and redirects you to the home page).

You can dynamically change the theme with the `stylesheet` filter:

```
function wpse109022_change_theme_name( $stylesheet ){
    //Change stylesheet to appropriate theme (based on cookiee for example)
    //$stylesheet should be the theme 'name', e.g. 'twentytwelve'
    return $stylesheet;
}
add_filter( 'stylesheet', 'wpse109022_change_theme_name' );
```

Please note Theme Switcher also uses the `template` filter, to do the same thing. I believe this is for backwards compatibility. (2.5??)

```
//add_filter( 'template', 'wpse109022_change_theme_name' );
```

*See source of theme switcher for more details*

---

Caveat: one problem is that WordPress doesn't remember templates between themes. For example:

- Create page and choose template A from your theme
- Change theme
- Select template from the new theme and re-save the page
- Switch back to original theme. The page no longer has template A

If you're using page templates you'll want WordPress to remember which template to use for which theme. I wrote a plug-in for this: http://wordpress.org/plugins/remember-my-template/

It essentially does the following:

- Every time a page is saved, store the template as meta data with key `_wp_page_template_{theme-name}`
- Filter the page's template via `get_post_metadata` filter and replace it with the appropriate template based on the theme.