# How to allow potential clients to preview a theme

Tags: previews

I have several themes installed in a Wordpress network.

New clients will receive a network sub-site.

I'd like them to be able to preview the available themes that are installed in Wordpress.

There are a handful of plugins that claim to allow this to happen, but none of them have been updated in the last couple of years.

Do such plugins not work in the recent versions of Wordpress?

Is it possible to create some code myself which will achieve the same effect as a plugin?

Thank you.

Comment: Which plugins are you referring to?

Comment: I think this question might be of help: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109022/can-i-obtain-differents-links-for-different-installed-theme/109032#109032. But don't take the fact they haven't been updated in quite a while as a sign they won't work. If the plug-in is small enough, chances are it hasn't needed updating. Only way to tell is to try them.

Comment: Theme-switcher works for me: http://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-switcher/. But if your clients are to be allowed access to the admin they can change themes the 'normal' way and you can simply remove their ability to install/edit plug-ins/themes.